# Error Tomcat 6 deployment Maven web application

Tags: maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I just "mavenize" a Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse Mars and i i think it's ok because i got my `project.war`.
I deploy it on Tomcat6 and i got this :

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) net.sf.acegisecurity.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [jasper-views.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jasper-views.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jasper-views.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

didn't know how to fix it ! any ideas ?

Comment: update your question with your sping config files

Comment: Thnx for the reply @vels4j , i thnik i resolve it by puttin all the spring config files Under `WEB-INF` directly and not Under `src\main\resources`.

Comment: @vels4j i edit the question

Comment: close the question by providing your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it by puttin all the spring config files Under `WEB-INF` directly and not Under `src\main\resources`